# c# code for combobox to set as optional value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

c# code for combobox to set as optional value?
I Have 3 Dev Express combo box,I need one combo box as optional how to achieve this?

My code is below:

```
         if (cmbEmployeeIDName.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt64(cmbEmployeeIDName.SelectedItem.Value);
            }

            if (cmbCompany.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                CompanyId = Convert.ToInt64(cmbCompany.SelectedItem.Value);
            }
            if (cmbDepartment.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                DepartmentId = Convert.ToInt64(cmbDepartment.SelectedItem.Value);
            }
```

Comment: you can always add empty value to each combobox you like to be optional - is there smth more you want to do?

Comment: ya can you provide Example code?

Comment: @user3036427 : you want to add some `default` text to combobox?

Comment: @user3036427 comboBox1.Items.Add(" ");

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set selected value to Combobox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688157/how-to-set-selected-value-to-combobox)

Comment: how to use in else if condition need to check in null also not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add default value to your Combobox like this

```
comboBox.Items.Add(" ");
```

Then, when you check for assignment:

```
if (comboBox.SelectedItem != null && comboBox.SelectedItem.Value != " ")
            {
                comboBoxId = Convert.ToInt64(comboBox1.SelectedItem.Value);
            }
```

And change `comboBox` to desired comboBox name.

Of course you can change `" "` for every string you like - just be sure it is unique from real choices

Comment: Any condition need to be used between this.

Comment: yep, my fault - fixed samle, change `combobox` to the one that should be optional

Comment: please be more precise - what exactly isn't working? any errors?

Answer (score 0):

you can compare with empty string

Try this:

```
if (cmbEmployeeIDName.SelectedItem !=null && cmbEmployeeIDName.SelectedItem.Value.Trim() != "")
{
    EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt64(cmbEmployeeIDName.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

Comment: i want use as optional whether it is null or not null?

Comment: Trim() throwing Error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mr.Nogard gave correct one without using Trim().