# How to display value from database into combobox list?

Tags: c#, combobox

I just started learning C# yesterday.  I am working with windows form. I could retrieve data from database and display them in combo box list.  But for data update, the `combo.SelectedValue` does not work. I have tried `combo.selectedItem`, but still, it does not work. What should i do?

```
selectedDescription = dr["value"].ToString().Split(',').ToList<string>(); 

if (dr["type"].ToString() == "multiple") {
    ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.DataSource = selectedDescription;
    combo.Width = 60;
    combo.Height = 27;
    combo.Location = new Point(currentX, currentY);
    combo.Tag = Id;
```

Code to retrieve data is as follows:

```
if (getVal != null) {
    foreach (DataRow ds in getVal.Tables[0].Rows) {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(ds["descId"].ToString()) == combo.Tag) {
            combo.SelectedValue = ds["val"].ToString();
        }
```

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work either:

```
List<string> str = (List<string>)combo.DataSource;
str.Add(ds["val"].ToString());
combo.DataSource = null;
combo.DataSource = str;
combo.Text = ds["val"].ToString();
```

Comment: @PranavSingh can you help me with this?

Comment: Are you trying to set the selected combo item based on what you are pulling from the database, or are you trying to get the value the user has selected from the combo?

Comment: @BrentMannering, I am trying to set the item based on the data i fetch from the database. But i also need to maintain the combo box list. Lets say the original combo list ={ 1, 2, 3} and user pick 2 as the value and save it into the database. So, if the user wants to update the data, the selectedItem will be 2 and 1 and 3 still on the list.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why, your code wouldn't be working. Perhaps try some of the following ideas from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688157/how-to-set-selected-value-from-combobox

Comment: @BrentMannering I think it has to do with the dotnet version im using. I'm using version 3.5