# get the combobox values from the row of the table and match

Tags: c#, .net

hello friends i am making one window base application 
now i have struck somewhere thats why i need help from you experts.
i want to get value form the row and match from the combobox.please find where i am wrong in this code. please make it crrect

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {


            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DSIIDC2;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            string str = "select * from addcaasedetails";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["addcaasedetails"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ds.Tables["addcaasedetails"].Rows[i]["caseno"] == casedetails.ValueMember)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                }
            }

            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

     }
```

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688157/how-to-set-selected-value-from-combobox

Comment: sir i did  this but now i am getting this error this error  "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Sir i have changed . but now i am getting

Answer (score 1):

have you check the type casting or null condition check in dataset?.
Please brief about it.

Comment: Sir Caseno type is int in database

Comment: have you set text member and value member appropriately?
Check this link for binding - 
http://net-informations.com/q/faq/combovalue.html

Answer (score 0):

In Place of `casedetails.ValueMember` use this `casedetails.SelectedValue`

**EDIT :**

```
if (ds.Tables["addcaasedetails"].Rows[i]["caseno"].ToString() == casedetails.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(ds.Tables != null)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["addcaasedetails"].Rows.Count; i++)
       {
         if (ds.Tables["addcaasedetails"].Rows[i]["caseno"] == casedetails.SelectedValue)
              {
                    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
              }
       }
    }`