# Getting selected item from Combobox and setting tag value

Tags: c#, combobox, simplewifi

For my application, the user can select their preferred WiFi Access point they want to connect to using a Combobox. I'm trying to convert the selected item from the Combobox to a string value to be used with the SimpleWifi library

This is my attempted solution:

```
ComboBox selectedItem = (ComboBox)cbWifiname.SelectedItem;
AccessPoint ap = (AccessPoint)selectedItem.Tag;
```

An example code solution that I'm trying to follow

```
ListViewItem selecteditem = listView2.SelectedItems[0];
AccessPoint ap = (AccessPoint)selecteditem.Tag;
```

But the result of my attempted solution of using a combobox, a debugging error showing "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Combobox''

Comment: SelectedItem is an object that can't be cast as combobox, this line is not correct `ComboBox selectedItem = (ComboBox)cbWifiname.SelectedItem`. what is the type of item you add there, is it a class or a string?

Comment: It's strings that are getting populated into the combobox

Comment: instead of string use a class, let me write an answer.

Comment: I'm using a foreach loop to add the WiFi APs into the combobox

Comment: foreach (AccessPoint ap in aps)

Comment: cbWifiname.Items.Add(ap.Name.ToString());cbWifiname.Tag = ap;

Comment: by the way, what are you using? winforms? wpf? add the appropriate question tag

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a combobox has a key, value pair, take a look on this
[How to set selected value from Combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688157/how-to-set-selected-value-from-combobox)

hope it helps!

Comment: So would I have to use a key, value pair to save the value selcted from the ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

I think you cast the selectedItem to the type Combobox, while it actually is a ComboBoxItem. Maybe this will help:

```
ComboBoxItem selectedItem = ((ComboBox)cbWifiname).SelectedItem;
```

or if you really want to have it as a string:

```
string selectedItem = ((ComboBox)cbWifiname).SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: If I try this solution, my next line below of ap1 = (AccessPoint)selectedItem.Tag shows an error saying "String does not contain a definition for Tag"

Comment: @SahilBora the second example i gave returns the string. the question is, do you really need a string or what does your code need. The class "AccessPoint" does not look like it accepts a string.

Answer (score 0):

lets say that your items are a class like:

```
public class Wifi
{
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public AccessPoint { get; set;}
     //....
}
```

Make display member to be the property you want to show:

```
cbWifiName.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Add to ComboBox like:

```
cbWifiName.Items.Add(new Wifi{ Name = "SomeName", AccessPint = somevalue});
```

Now you can get it like:

```
Wifi selected = (Wifi)cbWifiName.SelectedItem;
AccessPoint ap = selected.AccessPoint;
```